# is there any way to display variables of if match box

Tags: bash

Have one small bash script as below

```
#!/bin/bash
C="Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server #### #### "
if [ "$D(`grep Subsystem /etc/ssh/sshd_config`)" == "$C" ]
then
echo "Entry is proper in sshd_config file"
else
echo " Entry present in conf file $D "
echo ""
echo -e "it should be \t\t\t$C "
fi
```

But output is like as below

```
Entry present in conf file ($D--- is missing)

it should be      Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server #### ####
```

Is there any way to display $D of if match box ???

Comment: I think you just want to execute the grep like `"$(grep Subsystem /etc/ssh/sshd_config)"`. I don't know what the D is doing

Comment: What is a "if match box"?

Comment: @ Criket_007

does it really matters   ... i think nope.  ($ or $D... both are the same)

But the question is ... can v print it with echo ? like mentioned above. 

echo " Entry present in conf file $D "


@Jens

Sorry i don' t know the exact word ... but plz have a look code once ..you  will come to know.

Comment: @Jens I agree with you, but the brackets for the if are a "box" and the equals statement is a "match" is how I interpret it

Comment: LOL this is like a crypto game :) figure out the clues so you can solve it LOL sorry I am in a funny mood and this is not helping :)

Comment: @Sandy why do you need D? The only thing I see this script doing is checking if a file contains a line set by the variable $C. If you grep the file for $C and get at least one line back, then your file contains $C. There is no reason to store another variable

Comment: @cricket_007 .. above script is just for an example. Actually i have already made a script which around 200-300 lines long but defining variables each time or using same in echo statement 

(echo " Entry present in conf file `grep Subsystem /etc/ssh/sshd_config`" )

 is same like repeating the things again & again.  Hence was trying short way to print the same.

Comment: You can just print C. Like I said, D isn't necessary since it would match C anyways

Comment: @cricket_007 ... it is not necessary that will get $D=$C.. what if we have single # before the grepped string. 

C = Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server #### ####

D = #Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server #### ####

( #grep Subsystem /etc/ssh/sshd_config

#Subsystem      sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server)

now can't  print the $C ?  & hence only trying to print $D ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you were trying to achieve in the question.

Just change `C` to the string you want to search for.

```
#!/bin/bash

CONF_FILE="/etc/ssh/sshd_config" # the file to search
C="Port 22"                      # The string you want to find
RESULTS=$(grep "$C" $CONF_FILE)  # The grep result
LINES_FOUND=$(echo $RESULTS | wc -l) # How many lines contain C in CONF_FILE

if [ $LINES_FOUND -eq 0 ]; then # File does not contain C
    echo "Entry not present in conf file $CONF_FILE"
    echo ""
    echo -e "it should be \t\t\t$C"
else                            # At least one line matches
    echo "Entry is proper in $CONF_FILE"
fi
```

Comment: @crick_007... Thanks for the efforts. It works but using different way. But thank you & all experts for the help.